# Domain Project and Identity Project circular dependency

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, clean-architecture

I am currently working on implementing the Clean Architecture pattern using Entity Framework. However, I've encountered an issue related to the design of my Domain project. In this project, I need to define a "Wallets" table that should have a relationship with the "User" entity from the Identity project. Additionally, the "User" entity also needs to be aware of its associated "Wallets." It's important to note that a single user can have multiple wallets, while each wallet can only belong to one user. Now, I'm uncertain about the best approach to avoid this circular dependency and where I might have made a mistake in my architecture. Any advice or insights on how to resolve this situation would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried adding some interfaces, but I ran into another issue "he property 'Wallet.User' is of an interface type ('IApplicationUser'). If it is a navigation, manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type. Otherwise, ignore the property using the [NotMapped] attribute or 'Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'"

Comment: For identity purposes, why does a user need to know it's wallets?

Comment: Wallet belongs to the user, each user can have multiple wallets. I am confused with this approach, because I have 2 Context, and each time I need to connect something with Identity, I'm facing issues

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include more information about how the user entity is used in the domain library, what it is used for in the identity library, and why a user needs to know its wallets in both cases? My intuition says you are missing an entity, but it is hard to tell from the limited information in this question.

Comment: I am not sure what is missing from this context. User model, part of Identity, is placed inside Identity Project. Wallet entity is inside Domain model, where other entities are(every other except Identity models). User needs to know about wallet, because each user can have list of wallets. Maybe I need to place Identity entities inside Domain project instead of Identity project

Comment: “ User needs to know about wallet, because each user can have list of wallets. ” that’s not what that means. Given a user you need a list of their wallets. That doesn’t at all mean the user type even knows that wallets exist. Or that wallets know that users exist. Having a “relationship” does not require a source code dependency. Needing one to be able to call the other does.

Comment: Ok, maybe I forgot to mention that I am using code first approach, and yes, my model needs to know that wallet exists, because that is how I am creating tables.

Comment: I'm not asking about code dependencies. I'm asking about **business requirements**. That will drive your software design (well, it should anyways).

Comment: User is not included in the domain library, and that is where I am having issues. In my wallet class, I want to add User property, and I can't because I don't have reference to the Identity project

Comment: Give `Wallet` a `UserId`. When you need all wallets for a user, `select * from wallets where userid = …`. What’s the actual problem here?

Comment: You bringing up _tables_ (and _code first_, for that matter) should have nothing to do with a discussion on how you design your _domain_. This is the first hint that something's gone wrong in your understanding of what the domain represents and therefore how it should be designed. You need to go back to the drawing board on your understanding of clean architecture. Any answer given here will only be a patch to fix your current issue but not your overall design.

Comment: I gave userId to the wallet. It is working fine, however, my tables are not connected. @Flater I checked 1000 github repos like this, Identity and Domain are separated, and I don't know why. I didn't do anything wrong, I followed every possible instruction that I could find, just I didn't see anywhere this far

Comment: Identity and Domain are different things because Domain imposes relationships. It doesn't impose data structures. Be they tables, trees, or maps. Data structures are what need identity.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem comes from the fact that you are confusing (and trying to merge) two different entities that happen to have very similar names.

- `Identity.User`: The class with information about the person who provided his/her credentials and currently uses the application
- `Domain.User`: The user that the domain experts talk about and who owns a number of Wallets.

The fact that both are called `User` is not helping in keeping them apart, but they should be kept apart as they represent different ideas. Take for example the use case where I authorize you to perform actions on *my* Wallets. They would log in with their own credentials (`Identity.User` == pakerinjo), but they need to access my Wallets (`Domain.User` == BartvanIngenSchenau).

Comment: In that case, I need to create Domain User, and still need to connect it with the Identity User, which is pretty much the same as with the wallet

Comment: @pakerinjo, there is no need to connect Domain.User and Identity.User. They can exist independently.

Comment: But how will I know, when the  Identity.User logs in, who is the corresponding Domain user? Also what characteristic has the Domain user, that Identity.User doesn't?

Comment: The identity user would have a claim that contains the domain user ID. The domain application can then look up the user (by inspecting the authentication token for its claims). store the domain user ID in session, and use it for the database calls. The domain application should not know about the identity user table, just the claim and ID.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two different contexts here: `User`(s) and `Wallet`(s), I am going to assume you are using a surrogate key (such as a GUID) to identify each entity (`UserId` and `WalletId`).

I think the crux of your issue is how you are "connecting" the two contexts together, specifically you are trying to use the full objects instead of just the IDs.

If the Users and Wallets were implemented inside two different services:

- There would be no need for the Users service to have any reference to the Wallets (it's a different context).
- The Wallet service only needs the `UserId` to look up the attached Wallets.

Depending upon your preference for type safety you could either just use a GUID type (to represent the `UserId` in the Wallet service) or wrap each of the GUIDs in small reference classes (i.e.: UserId) - if you encounter circular dependencies, because of these reference types you can simply move all of them to a "references" package so that the main services don't create circular dependencies.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have 2 separate contexts, and there is no way of connecting them with full objects, I just used Id instead. I don't think I made any mistake with this approach, I was just confused. Now domain model has a wallet with userId as a property, and the identity user, has list of wallets as full objects, and it can work fine